# is_file produces a syntax error in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I use Ansible 2.3.2.0 for my project. In this project, I have a task using `is_file` test:

```
- name: Create repository.ini file
  template: src="{{ playbook_dir }}/../../../repository.ini" dest="/{{ repository_dir }}/repository.ini"
  when: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../../..//repository.ini"|is_file
```

This task produces the following error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

  template: src="{{ playbook_dir }}/../../../repository.ini" dest="/{{ jse_repository_dir }}/repository.ini"
  when: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../../../repository.ini"|is_file
                                                     ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
. . . .
```

I tried everything I could with no avail.

Comment: Do you mean I should have written `"{{ playbook_dir }}/../../../repository.ini|is_file"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When you start a YAML key value with a quote, you must quote the whole value, so if there are any other strings inside, you should use a different quotation mark (e.g., single quote + double quote).
2. Ansible expects the value of `when` to be a Jinja2 statement, so there is no need to use `{{` inside.
3. Because 2. that you need to use Jinja2 syntax for string concatenation `variable + 'string'`.

Combined, your conditional should be:

```
when: "(playbook_dir+'/../../../repository.ini')|is_file"
```

Comment: The pipe now outputs a deprecated warning: Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead of using `result|is_file` instead use `result is is_file`. This feature will be removed in version 2.9.